# "Ding" auf einer Speisekarte

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Was ist das korrekte Wort für Dinge auf einer Speisekarte?

Auf englisch würde ich "Item" benutzen, aber alle Übersetzungen für "Item" klingen irgendwie falsch.

"Gericht" deutet ja meiner Meinung nach eher auf eine ganze Mahlzeit hin, trifft also zum Beispiel auf Beilagen nicht zu.

Welches Wort würde hier am meisten Sinn machen, um ein "Ding" auf einer Speisekarte zu bezeichnen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es ist eine *Speise* karte. Auf ihr findet man *Speisen*. Eigentlich gehören Getränke in eine Getränkekarte, allerdings findet man oft kombinierte Speise- und Getränkekarten, die gegebenenfalls falsch bezeichnet sind.

Sofern die Speisekarte nur vollständige Gerichte enthält, kann man die Einträge auch als Gerichte bezeichnen. Aber wie du richtig gesagt hast, passt das auf einzelne Beilagen wie Pommes nicht.

Comment: Danke schon einmal für die Antwort. Gibt es vielleicht auch einen Begriff, der Speisen und Getränke umfasst?

Comment: Völlig richtig. In einer Speise-Karte stehen: Speisen

Comment: Und ganz heimlich schleicht sich das Wort "Eintrag" in die Antwort.

Comment: @LarsEbert: ein sehr allgemeines Wort, dass Speisen _und_ Getränke umfasst, könnte "`Angebot(e)`" sein: "`Für Sie haben ein reichhaltiges Angebot.`"

Comment: @Raphael Da hast du völlig Recht. Abstrakt gesehen ist es eine Liste mit Einträgen, unabhängig von den beteiligten Verzehrprozessen. Aber leider funktioniert unsere Sprache halt nicht immer abstrakt.

Comment: @LarsEbert Es gibt mehrere Begriffe, aber sie werden im allgemeinsprachlichen Kontext nicht oder kaum verwendet: `Produkte`, `Waren`, `Angebote`, `Zeug`, … Allgemeinsprachlich wird immer unterschieden, z. B. auch bei `zu Essen und zu Trinken`.

Comment: @Toscho Abstrakt gesehen besteht eine Liste aus *[Elementen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_(Datenstruktur))*, nicht Einträgen. Siehe auch meinen Kommentar zur Antwort von Raphael.

Answer (score 5):

Du könntest es konkret benennen: Auf der Karte stehen 20 Vorspeisen (davon 8 Suppen), 25 Hauptgerichte, 12 Beilagen und 15 Nachtische.

Allgemein könnte man Produkte oder Speisen sagen.

Comment: … und dann gibt es noch fertige Menüs.

Answer (score 3):

Eine Speisekarte ist eine Liste (von Gerichten) und Listen haben Einträge. Das würde man natürlich nicht verwenden, wenn man über die Speise an sich reden möchte, sondern lediglich für den Eintrag als abstrakte Entität.

Möchtest du bestellen bzw. einen Eintrag referenzieren, benutzt man üblicherweise "Nummer":

> Ich hätte gerne die Nummer 5 vorneweg, dann die 17 mit der 25 und als Nachspeise die 77.
>
> Hast du die [Nummer] 35 schon mal gegessen?

Comment: Nummern gibt es in vielen, insbesondere gehobenen Restaurants nicht. Ich kenne das eigentlich nur aus Schnellrestaurants, meistens mit Lieferservice.

Comment: Und Einträge gibt es nur in veränderlichen Listen, in die jeweils neue Daten eingetragen und die Listen so aktualisiert werden. Wenn in eine Liste nichts eingetragen wird – und auf einer Speisekarte werden keine Einträge gemacht –, sind darin auch keine Einträge aufgelistet.